# ADS -- Run Button Dimming

Tags: visual-studio, azure, t-sql, visual-studio-code, azure-data-studio

**Context:** I'm running some simple queries in Azure Data Studio to query and manipulate data in a local instance of SQL Server 2019.

[image]

**Question:** When I query the table via "Select", the Run button is accessible. As soon as I Truncate the table, the Run button dims & is no longer accessible --__-- Why!? Once the button dims seems I'm unable to execute any other queries in the same query window afterwards. SMH.

Kinda ridiculous that I need to even post this question given how simple these 2 queries are. I expect this button to be easily accessible, similarly to SQL Server Management studio. I read through the docs and dont see anything about this button dimming issue. ADS is built with similar components to VSC so experience or knowledge in that tool may help. Can someone please share any tips/tricks they know on how to fix this issue?

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/quickstart-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15